# CA and CSR Signing process

Tags: ssl, certificate

When I create my CSR on my server and send it to the CA for signing, why do I have to include my public key along with the CSR?

I understand the CA verifies the information and then signs the cert with its Private key but why do I have to send the servers Public key to the CA?

Comment: The CSR _contains_ your publickey so you shouldn't need to send it 'with', and it is in the CSR so the CA can put it in the certificate because the purpose of most certificates (for SSL/TLS and other things) is to authenticate an entity's publickey and a certificate not containing the publickey would be useless and worthless.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!